# How to initialize array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to dynamically initialize a variable array in javascript. I keep getting unexpected token illegal token errors.

in my current script, `serviceLimit = 10;` but it could be changed at any time.

Attempt #1

```
var jqSvcPhrase = {};
for(i=1; i<=serviceLimit; i++) {
  jqSvcPhrase[+ i +] = ''; // produces - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
}
```

Attempt #2

```
var jqSvcPhrase = {};
for(i=1; i<=serviceLimit; i++) {
  jqSvcPhrase\[+ i +\] = ''; // produces - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
}
```

Attempt #3

```
var jqSvcPhrase = {};
for(i=1; i<=serviceLimit; i++) {
  jqSvcPhrase\\[+ i +\\] = ''; // produces - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
}
```

Comment: i is integer not string

Comment: You're not trying to do that in jQuery. You're trying to do that in Javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is an integer type, so does not require concatenation. Try this:

```
var jqSvcPhrase = {};
for (i = 1; i <= serviceLimit; i++) {
      jqSvcPhrase[i] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhh... what's with all the `+`s?

```
var jqSvcPhrase = {};
for(i=1; i<=serviceLimit; i++) {
  jqSvcPhrase[i] = '';
}
```

Comment: Was simply copying and pasting prior code that worked.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Does this means the code was eval'd somewhere? I feel sorry for your code D:

Comment: No use of eval but thanks for your sympathies & concerns @aduch :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are declaring an object and not an array.
It should be `var jqSvcPhrase = [];` instead.
Furthermore the `+` is not needed. It has to be `jqSvcPhrase[i]`

Comment: Objects can still be accessed by index.

Comment: "I want to dynamically initialize a variable array [... ]" - you won't he able to use array functions when you got an object. If may be possible but better be careful here

Answer (score 0):

Why use curly brackets? Use square brackets for arrays.

```
var jqSvcPhrase = [];
for(i=1; i<=serviceLimit; i++) {
      jqSvcPhrase[i] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array syntax ([Manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) ):

> ```
> [element0, element1, ..., elementN] 
> new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]]) 
> new Array(arrayLength)
> ```

This should be :

```
var jqSvcPhrase = new Array(serviceLimit);
```

and it would make sense to initialize values:

```
for (x in jqSvcPhrase) { x = ''; }
```